# php user form registration

Tags: php, html, registration

I designed a webpage. One page contains an html user registration form:

```
      <form action="internal/signup.php" method="post" name="signupform" id="signupform">
        <table width="444" border="0" cellspacing="6">
          <tr>
            <th width="98"align="right" scope="col"><label id="fnamelabel" for="fnam">First Name :</label></th>
            <th width="286" align="center" scope="col"><input type="text" name="fnam" id="fnam" tabindex="1" /></th>
            <td width="34" align="center" scope="col"><div id="ll"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right" scope="row"> <label id="lnamelabel"  for="lnam"> Last Name :</label></th>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="lnam" id="lnam" tabindex="2" /></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="lj"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right" scope="row"><label id="youremail" for="email">Your Email :</label></th>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" /></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="lk"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right" scope="row"><label id="reemail" for="remail"> Password :</label></th>
            <td align="center"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="4" /></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="ll2"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right" scope="row"><label id="npass" for="password">Re-Password:</label></th>
            <td align="center"><input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" tabindex="5" /></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="lm"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right" scope="row"><label id="skill" for="bskill">Skilled Area :</label></th>
            <td align="center"><select name="bskill" id="bskill" tabindex="6">
                <option>Graphics and multimedia</option>
                <option>Art Works</option>
                <option>IT &amp; programming</option>
              </select></td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" align="left" scope="row" id="terms">By clicking &quot;Sign up&quot;, you are indicating that you have read and agreed our <a href="index.html">Terms &amp; conditions.</a></label></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
<td align="center"><div id="signupbutton"></div></td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp; 
    </form>
```

When I click the signup button it goes to signup.php and completes the registration, but I need to redirect to the user's page after signup is completed. (Similar to how Facebook or Twitter automatically direct to the user's page when the signup is completed)

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) after the registration is complete:

```
<?php
header('Location: users.php');
exit;
?>
```

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: It is better to *always* use the absolute path.

Comment: Use of `die();` or `exit();` is strongly recommended after header redirect.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// Redirect the user to wherever you want to go
header("Location: /users.php");

// Make sure none of the code beneath here is executed
die();
?>
```

This code must be sent before any content is.

More documentation can be found here: http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Use of `die();` or `exit();` is strongly recommended after header redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Remember to use [`die()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) or [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after `header()`. If you don't use one of them, your code will continue executing after redirection.

`header()` must be used before [any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php).